# How to get all keys of Android Preferences DataStore

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-jetpack-datastore

As mentioned by the title, is there any way to obtain all the keys stored in an Android Jetpack [Preferences DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore), e.g., `dataStore`

```
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting all keys

```
suspend fun Context.readAllKeys(): Set<Preferences.Key<*>>? {
    val keys = dataStore.data
        .map {
           it.asMap().keys
        }
    return keys.firstOrNull()
}
```

for getting value by it's key

```
suspend fun Context.getValueByKey(key: Preferences.Key<*>): Any? {
    val value = dataStore.data
        .map {
            it[key]
        }
    return value.firstOrNull()
}
```